# Matching HDMI monitor with audio

Tags: c#, c++, audio, monitor, hdmi

I am developing a video decoder with audio support. This component is written in C++ and used in a C# application. A customer likes to run this software using a Core i3 with integrated audio (Intel Display Audio) with a dual HDMI link.

Both HDMI connections will instantiate a HDMI output endpoint (speaker through the connected display).

**Goal:** 
Two videos and audio will play on the two different monitors.

For example;

- Video 1 with audio 1 will play on monitor 1 (+speaker 1)
- Video 2 with audio 2 will play on monitor 2 (+speaker 2)

**Question:**
Is it possible to detect, in code, which audio endpoint belongs to which monitor?

With NAudio, http://naudio.codeplex.com/, I can detect two sound outputs. Both can play on a different monitor. In GraphStudio, http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/, I can also detect two audio renderers. Still I don't see a way to match the monitor with the given sound output.

The solution can be in C++ or in C#.

Comment: In GraphStudio you will have different monikers and their display names. The difference possibly hints which monitor they belong to.

Comment: In the setup of the customer, two identical monitors are used, so in that case it would not help.

Comment: Moniker display names are unique, and are different for even for 2+ pieces of identical hardware.